# Unable to convert String to date

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdateformatter

This is my String "Oct 21 2013 12:55:22:000PM" And i am not able to convert it in the Date.
This is the code i have tried.

```
NSString * appLatUpdateStr = @"Oct 21 2013 12:55:22:000PM"
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"LLLL dd YYYY hh:mm:ss:SSSa"];
    NSDate *dbLastUpdateDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:appLatUpdateStr];
    NSLog(@"userUpdateResponse : %@",dbLastUpdateDate);
```

Its just giving me null value..

Comment: If you provide a string that the date formatter cannot parse it will return nil. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBGJDAE -"Return Value
A date representation of string interpreted using the receiver’s current settings. If dateFromString: can not parse the string, returns nil."

Comment: are you sure its `000PM` and not `000 PM`

Comment: You probably should use MMM, not LLLL.  Or at least LLL vs LLLL, since 4 characters implies the name is completely spelled out.  See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns .

Comment: Oh, and "yyyy", not "YYYY" -- the latter is a screwy "week of year" notation that often yields the wrong result.

Comment: And small "a", not "A".  Net:  "MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For month you need MMM not LLLL

```
NSString * appLatUpdateStr = @"Oct 21 2013 12:55:22:000PM"
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa"];
NSDate *dbLastUpdateDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:appLatUpdateStr];
NSLog(@"userUpdateResponse : %@",dbLastUpdateDate);
```

Comment: Probably LLL would work, but LLLL implies that the name is completely spelled out.